# Can you connect an HTML5 web socket to a Java Socket?

Tags: java, html, network-programming, websocket

I had set up a system that had a Java program running on a server and a Java applet embedded in a page on a client's browser and the two communicating via Java sockets. I'm wondering if I can switch over from a Java applet to just HTML5 and javascript, using a WebSocket on the client side for communication with the Java socket on the server.

Is there a simple way to make a WebSocket communicate with a Java Socket?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3202188/1101070) question/answer is probably what you're looking for. You haven't mentioned any details about your environment but that answer is quite comprehensive.

Comment: To put the answer to this succinctly: No, you cannot connect a Java Socket to a WebSocket. However, there are server-side WebSocket implementations out there for Java.

Comment: I would need to take one of these and modify my existing server program to pass its data using that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to make a WebSocket communicate with a Java Socket?

From what I understand, WebSocket works by the client side opening a port 80 connect to the server side, and sending a variant HTTP 1.1 request to the server to negotiate a WebSocket connection.  If the server recognizes this, it will send a suitable response, and then allow the still open TCP connection to be used for full-duplex client-server interactions.

It looks like it would be possible to quickly put together a server-side that *just* understood WebSocket negotation and not full HTTP.  However, I think you are better off looking at existing WebSocket implementations, including those embedded in HTTP servers / protocol stacks.

[This Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations) compares a number of WebSocket implementations, and should help you in deciding which server-side implementation to use.

But to directly answer your literal question, a WebSocket client can only connect to a WebSocket-aware server; i.e. that one that can perform the initial negotiation.  (On the client side, you could implement starting from a bare Socket, but you would need to implement all of the "HTTP stuff" on top of that ... for the setup phase.)

Answer (score 4):

Nope, you cannot communicate using regular sockets with client WebSockets.

WebSockets are special HTTP requests, with an upgrade in the HTTP Header, and a standard protocol to establish a connection (see the [official RFC doc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)).